# How to define a common lisp slot definition metaobject?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos, mop

I would like to define a common lisp slot definition metaobject in order to allow for providing new options when writing the details of a slot on a class.

For example

```lisp
(defclass test3 ()
  ((world :my-new-option T)))
```

Just like `:initform` could be provided, I want to be able to provide a new option for that slot. Furthermore, I would then like to be able to have a function that, given class, can then return the value of the provided option.

Example:

```lisp
(my-new-option-value (find-class 'test3))
=> T
```

I tried defining it as a subclass of `c2mop:standard-direct-slot-definition`, but didn't really know where to go from there to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [additional properties to slot definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986977/additional-properties-to-slot-definition/21988238#21988238) by @RainerJoswig with some modifications so that it works in SBCL and probably in all Common Lisps that support c2mop.

```lisp
(defclass foo-meta-class (c2mop:standard-class) ())

(defclass foo-standard-direct-slot-definition (c2mop:standard-direct-slot-definition)
  ((foo :initform nil :initarg :foo
        :accessor foo-slot-value
        )))

(defclass foo-standard-effective-slot-definition (c2mop:standard-effective-slot-definition)
  ((foo :initform nil :initarg :foo
        :accessor foo-slot-value
        )))

(defmethod c2mop:direct-slot-definition-class ((class foo-meta-class) &rest initargs)
  (find-class 'foo-standard-direct-slot-definition))

(defmethod c2mop:effective-slot-definition-class ((class foo-meta-class) &rest initargs)
  (find-class 'foo-standard-effective-slot-definition))

(defmethod c2mop:validate-superclass ((class foo-meta-class) (superclass c2mop:standard-class))
  t)

(defclass foo ()
  ((a :initarg :a :foo :bar))
  (:metaclass foo-meta-class))


(inspect (c2mop:class-direct-slots (find-class 'foo)))
```

Now, given a slot, we can check the value of the `:foo` option like this:

```lisp
(foo-slot-value given-slot)
```

So for example:

```lisp
(foo-slot-value (car (c2mop:class-direct-slots (find-class 'foo))))
=> :BAR
```